# So I created personas. What's next?

Tags: users, wireframe, experience, task-flow, scenarios

I'm doing UX for the mobile app for the first time. I have developed user personas and don't know what to do next to get to the visual design. I suppose I have to create these things: application map, user scenarios, use cases, user stories, user flows, experience map, task flows, attribute (content) map, wireframes, wireflows. I didn't find a step by step guide on UX that would include all those steps and their importance in the design process. I'm confused... Here is how I understand the process:

1. **Create personas**
2. **User story** (to highlight needs of each persona, even though it's written in the persona description. Maybe it's the most important conclusion from the persona research and needs to be written as a separate step one more time? Also **use case** has already defined user needs. So what's use of **user story**?)
3. **Use case** for each persona (to get detailed user - system interaction process)
4. **User scenario** - to get more insights into environment in which user decides to use an app.
5. **Experience map** - to get insights into circumstances and user's emotions.
6. Using **use case** data create **application map**. Or **user flow** should be on this step? I suppose **Information Architecture** development begins on this step.
7. Knowing all screens and pop-up dialogs **attribute (content) map** should be done.
8. Using **user flow** as a reference for all possible interactions **wireframes** can be designed
9. Now when I have all **wireframes** and can tell from the **user flow** how they are linked I can build **wireflows**.
10. **Visual design** - when wireframes are ready color, typography and other visual elements can be applied.

What about task flows, where do they fit into this process? Is this step by step guide complete or did I miss something? 
Also a step where I need to create an **application map** is difficult for me because I don't know what to take as a reference point designing all those screens and pop-up dialogs. I suppose **user flow** is good for that as it contains all screens. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it all depends. Each project has its particularities, you'll have different resources, time, budget and so on. There's always the temptation to do more and to over analyse to play safe, which of course increases times, and sometimes affecting the initial research because data is no longer accurate.

What I mean with this is that your list and process is as complete as you want it to be and there's not a *set in stone* list since no project is the same. However, you may get some ideas on how a typical process looks (in a big company with lts of budget and resources) from the following resources

[image]
*Credit: Tiffany Ho*

[image]
*credit: Arthi Amaran*

And also:

- [**UX Checklist**](http://uxchecklist.github.io)
- [**User Experience Design Process**](http://cathkitt.com/ux_process_flow.html)

## In short

This is not the same in every case for every person, client or UX team. just make sure the data you get is as complete and accurate as possible, and from there it will be a lot easier to get to the best solutions for any UX problem